# How I do SOAP xsi:type with PHP

Tags: php, soap

I need to do following structure to SOAP call:

```
    <a>$a</a>
    <b>$b</b>
    <c>
    <d>
        <e>$e</e>
        <f>
            <g>$g</g>
            ...
        </f>
        <i>$i</i>
        <j>
            <k>$k</k>
            <l>$l</l>
            <foo type="bar">
                <asd>$asd</asd>
                ...
            </foo>
        </j>
    </d>
</c>
```

Tricky part is , without it I could just do multidimensional array and call $client->method($array_format); and everything else works, even  when I just do 'bar' => array('id' => 'foo')b but with type I can't do that cause bar is subtype of foo.
I have tried to do that one part with SoapVar, but it doesn't work either. Server still complains that request need to have foo, when I give foo, it says that it must have one of bar's as subtype.
I only have example of a full document what server side expects to get, and they normally get requests from Java/C clients where this isn't apparently a problem.
How I can either send manually constructed document or get this working with array-format and use SoapClient -class?

Comment: Did you try `SoapParam`? http://php.net/manual/en/soapparam.soapparam.php

Or what this comment says?  http://php.net/manual/en/soapparam.soapparam.php#114146

Comment: Tried for that one part, but since it has inner nodes and document has other stuff, I didn't manage to get that working with SoapParam either. It complains that I miss foo.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should at least use the native php SoapClient class.

But nowadays, WSDL to PHP generator really eases the work such as the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project.

Using the generated package, it will be as clear as crystal

Comment: This looks promising, but only thing I get is "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'GeneratorOptions' not found..." when try to follow instructions.

Comment: because you have to use the namespace WsdlToPhp\PackageGenerator\ConfigurationReader\ before the class name, didn't your IDE autocomplete it?

Comment: Thanks, that information wasn't visible in instructions. Now how do I create Generator object? That's not obvious either and doesn't work with same namespace either. Class name Generator is reserved, so it obviously needs some namespace before it.

Comment: Sorry but which IDE are you using? Anyway, this is WsdlToPhp\PackageGenerator\Generator\Generator

Comment: Managed to get something useful out, but still complains same. Foo must have subtype bar. Also I had to modify auto generated classes bit cause server accepts only arrays, not objects for some parts.

Comment: Feel free to submit a issue on the Github project issues. Normally, it works fine with almost any SOAP WS, almost because the native PHP SoapClient class lacks from some features